# ValueError while adding tensor with scalar

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm using the following code to add tensor with scalar as follows,

```
self.seen  = tf.compat.v1.assign_add(self.seen , 1.)
```

Unfotunately it throws the following error,

```
> ValueError: Operation name: "AssignAddVariableOp" op:
> "AssignAddVariableOp" input: "AssignAddVariableOp/Variable" input:
> "Const" attr {   key: "dtype"   value {
>     type: DT_FLOAT   } }  is not an element of this graph.
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

According to Tensorflow docs,

> Unlike tf.math.add, this op does not broadcast. ref and value must have the same shape.

So you can't use this to add scalars and tensors.

Comment: Why don't you use `tf.add` or simply `+`?